# $uv$ is harmonic if and only if $u+icv$ is analytic for some real c

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ and $v$ be non constant harmonic functions on a complex domain. Prove that $uv$ is harmonic if and only if $u+icv$ is analytic for some real $c$.

I can prove the "if" part. I am having some trouble with the "only if" part.

My argument is : $uv$ is harmonic implies $u_xv_x+u_yv_y=0$. This means that

$<u_x,u_y>$ is perpendicular to $<v_x,v_y>$. This implies that $<v_x,v_y> = c<-u_y,u_x>$. This proves the result. My question is - does this sound rigorous enough?

Comment: The proportionality constant could depend on the point in the plane, you have to exclude that possibility.

Comment: I see the catch. I assume that I have to use the fact $u$ and $v$ are harmonic to rule out that possibility. I started with $v_x =-c(x,y)u_y$ and $v_y = c(x,y)u_x$ and used $\triangle v = 0$ to arrive at $c_yu_x - c_xu_y = 0$. Then I used $v_{xy} = v_{yx}$ to arrive at $c_xu_x =c_yu_y = 0$. This gives me after elimination $(c_x^2 + c_y^2)u_x = 0$ and $(c_x^2 + c_y^2)u_y = 0$. Thus $u$ is constant.

Comment: Looks good. The last sentence should read "Thus $c$ is constant" of course.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, that's my style. Do most of it correct with a neat typo at the end. :(
Do you think I should post this as an answer to close the question?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u_xv_x + u_yv_y = 0 \implies <u_x, u_y> = c(x,y) < v_y, -v_x>$

$ \implies u_x = c(x,y)v_y$ and  $u_y = -c(x,y) v_x$.

Using $\triangle u =0$ and $\triangle v =0$ on this we get, $c_xv_y -c_yv_x =0$.

Again using $u_{xy} -u_{yx} =0$ we get $c_yv_y + c_xv_x=0$.

Eliminating $v_x$ and $v_y$ from the above equations leads to

$(c_x^2 +c_y^2)v_x =0$ and  $(c_x^2 +c_y^2)v_y =0$ which means $c$ is a constant.

Hence $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u+icv$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

As observed by the OP, if $u$, $v$ and $uv$ are harmonic in $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ (open and connected), then
$$
u_xv_x+u_yv_y=0,
$$
and thus the there is a $c=c(x,y)$ such that
$$
(v_y,-v_x)=c(x,y)(u_x,u_y), \qquad (\star)
$$
with the above valid wherever $(u_x,u_y)\ne (0,0)$. But this can only happen in a subset of $\Omega$ without a limit in $\Omega$, otherwise the analytic function $f=u+iw$, where $w$ is a harmonic conjugate of $w$ would be constant.

$(\star)$ implies that
\begin{align}
0=v_{xx}+v_{yy}=-c_xu_y -cu_{xy}+c_yu_x+cu_{xy}=-c_xu_y+c_yu_x, \\
0=(v_y)_x-(v_x)_y=c_xu_x+cu_{xx}+c_yu_y+cu_{yy}=c_x u_x+c_yu_y,
\end{align}
and thus $(c_x,c_y)=(0,0)$, as it is perpendicular and parallel to a nonzero vector. Hence $c=c(x,y)$ is constant, and thus $cv$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u$.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ need to be harmonic as well. Here $\triangle v = 2$ and $\triangle u \not=0$ as well.